# How to create errors in Azure Service Bus for testing?

Tags: azureservicebus

How to create errors in Azure Service Bus?
What is most simple way to create error?
What are typical way how errors happens in production system?
I would like to test how errors are collected to diagnostics logs in storage.

Comment: Are you asking for a list of possible SB possible errors?

Answer (score 0):

A good starting point would be to review the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messaging-exceptions) about possible errors and how to handle those.

If you're asking about mimicking broker errors, that'd be a challenge. Some of those errors cannot be generated on the client-side at all. Some can be. For those that can, I have created a helper package [ServiceBus.Mischief](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceBus.Mischief/).

A way to achieve what you're asking for is to come up with a simple prototype of what you're trying to do with Azure Service Bus and run that 24/7, logging errors and issues you encounter. Using a Standard tier you can provision multiple POCs/spikes and learn about Service Bus behaviour and various aspects that need to be considered when running in production.

If you're looking for a list of TODOs, that would be hard to come up with as it will be quite a long list. I strongly recommend going over [service documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/) first.